# SU Retag Request: [applications] --> [software]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, software, applications

[applications](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/applications) might benefit from being merged to [software](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software).

Comment: Is there any reason this is posted here, and not created as Tag synonyms?

Comment: At a guess @Diago, it's because Tom doesn't have enough presense in [either](http://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A9666+%5Bapplications%5D) [tag](http://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A9666+%5Bsoftware%5D) to be able to do so directly.

Comment: @Diago: The page tells me: Users with more than 2500 reputation on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms.

Comment: @TomWij That's fine. But can you motivate some of these. Looking at it I am not sure merging tags or creating synonyms are correct without some background. There isn't always time to investigate every merge request and see if it is valid or not.

Comment: @Diago: Well, people that are interested in cleaning the tags are free to vote. And a high vote count could then point out a moderator might want to look into this... You don't have to go through every single request. :-)

Comment: @TomWij Meta SU does not have enough traffic to make voting a valid way of checking. At some point someone has to go through each request, and since tag synonyms are there, maybe raise it in chat so that it can get faster attention.

Comment: @Diago: Nice idea, will drop a link to a tag search list of non-completed/rejected retag-requests on the chat in the near future... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have merged [software](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software) into [application](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/application) and created the synonym for it.