# Can [pc], [programs] be obliterated? And [hardware], [software] again?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Reference 1: [SU Retag Request: [tag:applications] --> [tag:software]](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1925/su-retag-request-applications-software)

Reference 2: [Can [tag:hardware] and [tag:software] be obliterated?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2017/can-the-hardware-and-software-tags-be-obliterated)

**Can we obliterate [pc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pc) and  [programs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/programs) as well?**

On the same par: **Can [hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware) and [software](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software) be obliterated again?** They don't seem blacklisted.

Seems [app](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/app) is empty or has been renamed since I made this post.
The two questions under [applications](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/applications) have been untagged.

Comment: +1 I approve this message

Comment: +1 I agree as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I destroyed [pc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pc) and [programs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/programs) -- note that there are some [untagged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions now.

I also destroyed any remaining hardware and software tags, and added hardware and software to the tag blacklist.

Comment: Is it normal that I still see them 2 mins after you said this? **Edit:** Oh, the tags on them are gone, I see...

Comment: @tom we cache lists of ids for about 5 minutes